# Javascript- how to find the minimum of an array using a function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
function min() {
  var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  array = array.length === 1 && isNumeric(array[0].length) ? array[0] : array;

  var min = array[0];
  var i, count;
  for (i = 1, count = array.length; i < count; i++) {
    if (array[i] < min) min = array[i];
  }
  return min;
},
```

I don't understand why the following line was placed in, what is its purpose?

```
array = array.length === 1 && isNumeric(array[0].length) ? array[0] : array;
```

Comment: That whole function seems way too complicated when you can just call `Math.min.apply(null, arrayOfNumbers)` OR `Math.min.call(null, num1, num2, num3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `condition ? returnIfTrue : returnIfFalse` is called a ternary operator.
- `array.length === 1 && isNumeric(array[0].length)` means "If `array` has a single element and that first element is itself an Array".
- `a = ternaryOperator` means set `a` to the result of the ternary operator.

These three together mean that you can call `min` in two ways:

`min(1, 2, 3)` or `min([1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 2):

That line allows passing numbers directly as arguments or passing a single array as the first argument:

```
min(1,2,3);
min([1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor this function into

```js
var min = (...args) => Array.isArray(args[0]) ? Math.min(...args[0]) : Math.min(...args);

document.write("<pre>" + min([1,2,3,4,-1]) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + min(1,2,-3,4,-1) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Arrow functions are a bit of a stretch here. Browser support is not really there yet.

Comment: True.. Safari doesn't support arrows but i just wanted to demonstrate the idea. It's no big deal to implement the same thing in conventional ways. It's also worth to notice that exactly the same `...args` syntax work both as  rest and spread operator.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is confusing, try doing something like this

```
var min = 1000000;
 var temp = 0;
if ( element < min){
 temp = element; 
 min = element;
 }
```